# Failing to alter data in database

Tags: php, mysql

The purpose of this script is to allow the user to add "money" to their account and then withdraw the money. This whole task is a fictitious one for school so i'm not worried about security or using real money or anything like that.

so far the user has the ability to add money. But I cannot get the withdraw to work.

```
    $funds = $_POST['funds'];
    $withdraw_or_add = $_POST['list'];


if($withdraw_or_add == "add"){
    $sql = "UPDATE users ". "SET userFunds = $funds ". "WHERE userId = 1";
} else {
    $info = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId = '1'"));
    $new_fund == $info['userFunds'] - $funds;
    $sql = "UPDATE users ". "SET userFunds = $new_fund ". "WHERE userId = 1";
}
```

This is the code I have written for this section. When i used it on the server i get this message in return.

> Could not update data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE userId = 1' at line 1

My knowledge of PHP is not fantastic. So any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `users ` in your query is any constant or table name itself?

Comment: @MilanGupta It's the name of the table.

Comment: Try writing query like this: `"UPDATE users SET userFunds = ' ".$funds." '  WHERE userId = 1";`

Comment: @MilanGupta Okay i did that and now when i withdraw "money" it takes the number that should be used for subtraction and just uses that as the new figure. So when i want to take away 5 from 20 it should be 15. But instead it just changes to 5.

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$funds = $_POST['funds'];
$withdraw_or_add = $_POST['list'];


if($withdraw_or_add == "add")  
{
  $sql = "UPDATE users SET userFunds = '".$funds."' WHERE userId = 1";  
  $sql =  mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}   
else  
{
  $info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId = '1'");
  $info = mysql_fetch_assoc($info);
  $new_fund = $info['userFunds'] - $funds;
  $sql = "UPDATE users SET userFunds = '".$new_fund."' WHERE userId = 1";  
  $sql =  mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem. It is still changing the value to what it should be subtracting.

Comment: To confirm: `$funds = 5` and `$info['userFunds'] = 20` are the values and you are getting incorrect value in `$new_fund`. Is it so?

Comment: yes. So in this example `$new_fund` should = 15. But for me it's equaling 5.

Comment: Did your print value of `$new_fund` or you are checking updated record record in DB?

Comment: checking in the database.

Comment: I just added `$sql =  mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` in answer. Looks like your update query was not being fired at all. Can you check with edited answer?

Comment: Now it's returning  `No database selected`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128163/discussion-between-craig-harkins-and-milan-gupta).